# How to Rollback transactions in PHP ADODB

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, adodb, rollback

I'm trying to use DB-transactions using ADODB in php (mysql-driver),
though for some reason I cannot get the transactions working.
Currently the code looks a bit like this (simplified in order to make things sequential)

```
// Start DB-connection
$db = NEWADOConnection('mysql');
$db->debug = false;
$db->disableBlobs = false;
$db->PConnect($host, $login, $password, $database); or die ("Connection failed");

// Start DB-transaction
$db->autoCommit = false; // According to doc, this should not be needed
$db->SetTransactionMode("SERIALIZABLE");
$db->StartTrans();

// Update some value
$statement = $db->Prepare("UPDATE tableName SET column=? WHERE id=$id");
$result = $db->Execute($statement, array($newValue));

// Do a rollback
$db->FailTrans(); // According to doc, indicates that CompleteTrans will rollback
$db->CompleteTrans();

// Close connection
$db->Close();
```

As far as I understood the documentation of ADODB, the code should work,
though for some reason, the table is still updated after running this code.

Has anyone an idea which configuration I have forgotten to change?

Thanks in advance

JVApen

---

Some background info:

```
PHP-version: PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.9
ADODB-version: V5.18
Documentation I've based my code on: http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm
```

Before someone comments on a strange thing in the code:
Yes, I'm using prepared statements and string-concat together for queries,
though $id is something which I can control, while $newValue is some input-argument.

Comment: curious: why do you use ADO DB instead of PDO / MySQLi ?

Comment: For one thing: habit; for another, to have at least on issue less when I want to change db. Which for maria-db would not be that much of an issue, though if I would like to use postgres, it could be useful.

Comment: @JVApen, ADOdb is written by one author and the last release is like 3 years ago. Be careful about using ADOdb.

Comment: @Pacerier: I actually had the same worries when I started using it, though with the 5.19 release from april 2014 and quick response on the bugs I logged, I'm not that worried. And if so, I can still which to native calls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the problem,
the issues does not appear to be in ADODB (Though it should have warned).

Using MySQL with MyISAM-tables instead of InnoDB-tables makes sure that transactions are not supported.
If you would have a mix of both, transactions is only supported for the InnoDB-tables.

Transformed all tables to InnoDB, and the problem appears to be solved now.